# Convert yolov7 weight and configuration file

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, yolov7

How can I convert yolov7 .yaml and .pt files into .cfg and .weights files???!

I've already tried using pre-existing .cfg and .weights extensions and they worked fine.

I need to use these files with an OpenCV code, so I need those extensions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.